# Android Studio Blanking out Custom Designed Logo for ActionBar When Adding Image Asset

Tags: android, image, android-actionbar, android-studio

So I'm trying to add an image which has a width of 300 pixels and height of 100 pixels (which I can easily change if need be):

[image]

I want to replace the 'app icon' that appears in the upper left of the ActionBar of the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) to use my logo instead of the app launcher icon. However when I right click Android Studio click 'New' and then 'Image Asset' and set the following:

Asset Type: Action Bar and Tab Icons

Foreground: Image

Theme: CUSTOM

Foreground color:  [0,0,255] which is slightly different from my logo color, but I leave it be since it's default

The foreground color washes over my actual image:

[image]

How do I add my logo as an image asset such that it scales nicely & automatically for MDPI, HDPI, etc to be used to replace the default launcher icon in the upper left without me having to create custom image sizes for each in an image editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by setting a foreground color for the logo.

Using a logo in place of the app icon is really simple. Just specify the android:logo attribut on your application tag in the manifest, and set your android:displayOptions for the action bar style to useLogo.

```
<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

In terms of where to put your image, you want to work out which dpi bucket is correct for your image, and then put it into the correct folder. You could do this by trial and error. Simple copy your image to the res/drawable-xhdpi folder, and see what it looks like. Android will handle scaling the image for you.

Comment: When you add an image asset via right click -> 'New' 'Image Asset' and select Theme: CUSTOM it automatically adds a Foreground color attribute which I didn't really want/need. Your method does the trick though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:
Just drag and drop your wanted .png, .jpg ... file to the AndroidStudio project explorer -> res -> drawable